# New Regulator = Air in my Beer LInes?

Tags: keg

Had to replace a faulty regulator for my two tap system.  Hooked everything up, changed nothing else, not the temp in the fridge, not the kegs, etc.  Literally just the regulator.

Now I have air bubbles forming in the beer line after an hour or so of no use.  Is it possible that the problem is from the CO2 regulator?

Some additional background: current pressure is at 8 or so.  When I had my "faulty" regulator prior to this -- the gauge would read 0 no matter what the line pressure was. To that end, it is entirely possible I overcarbonated the keg itself by thinking the tank was empty and cranking it up.

It is also worth noting the beer tastes metallic -- did I overcarbonate and this will resolve over time?  I am going to drop it down to 4 or 6 for now and bleed the kegs aggressively.

I am running a commercial tap system (Sankey).  This is not relative to homebrew.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the pressure set at? Those bubbles are almost certainly CO2.

Comment: 8-9 right now.  Edited above.

Comment: If you are seeing air in the line then you might have a leak.  Take some soap solution and spray the connection areas, and turn up the co2 pressure.  See if you can spit bubbles coming out anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the bubbles are most probably just CO2 coming out of suspension. This can be due to temperature diffences between the beer and the beerline, or because of something causing the agitation (dirt in the beerline).

If the beer is overcarbonated this will happen quicker. Try to get the beer & beerline at the same temp, or get the beerline even colder.

Comment: I would second this, especially if there's a metallic taste.  That sounds like carbonic acid to me, which is to say WAAAY too much CO2.

Comment: Thanks all. Eventually it resolved at a lower CO2 setting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great site http://www.draughtquality.org/

Download the [free manual](http://www.draughtquality.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/DQM_Full_Final.pdf) and I am sure it will help you.